# Phonegap android app: the initial run behaves weirdly

Tags: android, cordova

Actually, I am bothering the problem of screen size of phonegap apps.
I have found a solution from this site (http://ryangillespie.com/phonegap.php).
By using javascript and the feature of css3, it works.

The code is following:

```
var designWidth = 480; // zoom to fit this ratio
var designHeight = 762; // not 800 b/c top bar is 38 pixels tall
var scaleChange = 1; // % change in scale from above #s

function zoomScreen() {
    var docWidth = window.outerWidth;
    var docHeight = window.outerHeight;

    if (docWidth != designWidth) {
        var scaleX = docWidth / designWidth;
        var scaleY = docHeight / designHeight;
        if (scaleX < scaleY) {
            $('body').css('zoom', scaleX);
            scaleChange = scaleX;
        } else {
            $('body').css('zoom', scaleY);
            scaleChange = scaleY;
        }
    }
}
```

But, the problem is: it only behave correctly in the initial run. When I shut down the app and restart it, the screen size behave wrong.

There is also one more weird behavior. After I try to reload the page by

```
window.location.reload()
```

The screen size behaves correctly.

How to fix it?
This is my first post. If I miss some of the information, I would clarify.

Answer (score 0):

That method might only be called when the app creates the view initially, depending on how you have the app working, there may be an 'onCreate' or 'onSurfaceCreated' method that is getting called to correctly set the changes.  Then when you bring the app up again, the surface has already been created, and so that app doesn't try and re-create it and somehow it's not in the right state.  If you determine that you need to reload the settings every time, have the app call that reload method in the 'onSurfaceModified', or 'onResume', or whatever, or try to figure out how the view is getting modified between runs.

Comment: I have tried to call the reload function on the "onCreate" state, and it behaves properly. Thank you.